# Safari extension that spoofs user-agent?

Tags: javascript, safari, user-agent, safari-extension

Is it possible to spoof the user agent using a Safari extension? I know that Safari itself is able to spoof using the Develop menu item, but it's too limited for me.

As far as I know, Safari extensions use 'start' and 'end' scripts, but both are executed *after* the document has been loaded, so I can't use those scripts to change the user agent via JavaScript.

I'm not too sure about this, only started looking into extensions today, so maybe someone has another idea?

Comment: How is Develop > User Agent > Other… too limited for you?

Comment: The user agent you set using the Develop menu item isn't persistent. I want to build an extension that spoofs the user agent every time I go to a specific website.

Comment: 12 (!) years later still no persistent user agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just looking for a way to quickly change between User Agents in Safari, you might beable to use [Applescript UI Script](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html). Basically it can simulate almost any user interface click/type, which would allow fairly quick changing of User Agents.

Answer (score 1):

If you go the AppleScript UI Scripting route, [as mentioned by Kendal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4118857/1661012), you can change the User Agent by the name they shown on Safari’s menu:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        click menu item "Safari — iOS 10 — iPad" of menu "User Agent" of menu item "User Agent" of menu "Develop" of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```